# Does it matter that a servicestack.net OPTIONS request returns a 404?

Tags: c#, http, servicestack, cors

I'm using the method described at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api to enable CORS. This seems to work, i.e. I get the correct Access-Control headers back in the response, but the status code is a 404. Does this matter?

For completeness I'd prefer to return a non-error code. Reading http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html it seems as though I ought to be returning a 200. What's the best way to do this?

The service method definition is:-

```
    [EnableCors]
    public void Options(ApiKeyRequest apiKeyRequest)
    {
    }
```

The HTTP request is:-

```
OPTIONS http://myreallycoolwebapi/apikeyrequests HTTP/1.1
Host: myreallycoolwebapi
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, content-type, accept
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8000/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

and the response is:-

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 17 Nov 2012 18:06:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

404
```

#### UPDATE 1

This is my resource type.

```
[Route("/apikeyrequests", "POST")]
public class ApiKeyRequest : IReturn<ApiKeyRequest>
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The POST requests work just fine.

Comment: Can you show the [EnableCors] service that you're using and the request you're making that's giving you a 404?

Comment: @mythz I've added those - let me know if you need more info

Comment: Damn, just come across this issue myself. Would have expected a 405 (according to HTTP Spec) rather than a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still haven't seen anything matching the expected route `/apikeyrequests`.

Do you have a custom route definition, e.g:

```
[Route("/apikeyrequests")]
public class ApiKeyRequest {}
```

Added for the request?

Comment: See Update 1. Do I need to omit the "POST" argument? Or should I change it to "POST", "OPTIONS"?

Comment: Yes POST Route will **only** match HTTP POST requests. You can remove the filter so it applies to all verbs or add specifically OPTIONS (amongst the other verbs you want the Route to match on). On a similar note, you can use **Any(ApiKeyRequest req)** instead of **Options(ApiKeyRequest req)** to be able to handle and add filters to **any** route.

Comment: Thanks very much. Adding OPTIONS to the Route attribute did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The CORS spec itself explicitly indicates that a non-200 preflight response is an error. See the "If the response has an HTTP status code that is not 200" section here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

I don't know what the motivation is for this requirement. Perhaps its because a 404 could introduce confusion as to whether the endpoint actually exists.

Comment: +1 I guess there's more than 'question' in my post and this certainly answers one of them, thanks.